# Given a real number, find the lowest value you can add to it to create a real palindrome

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a real number, `n`, find the lowest real number, `m`, such that `n+m` is a real palindrome.

> **For example**
>   If the number is 101.099 , to add to 0,002 , we get the real palindrome 101.101 . Another example would be the number 13.31 , which is already a real palindrome and must add 0 so that it stays that way. A final example is the number 100.9 , which should add 0.1 so that the number becomes 101.

Can anyone offer an algorithm/some advice to help me solve this problem?

Comment: There is no lowest value that gives a real palindrome. For any non-palindromic real number, you can add an arbitrarily small fraction of the reversal of the digits and get a palindrome. For 101.099, I can add 0.000990101, 0.0000990101, 0.00000990101, etc.

Comment: That's not symmetrical on the decimal point though, like in the first example.  The problem is a bit vague.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the decimal point was considered significant (although being able to discard it in the case of 100.9 then looks a little strange).

Comment: Yeah, that second solution 101 seems inconsistent to me :-)

Comment: Are irrational numbers palindromes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the decimal is relevant to the number being palindromic.

**Observation 1:** the problem you provided is equivalent to finding the smallest "real palindrome" which is larger than the given value, and then taking the difference of this palindrome and the given number.

**Observation 2:** Since every real number only has one decimal point we know that the decimal part of the number must be a mirror of the integer part. So given the integer part you can generate the only "real palindrome" that can be associated with it. For instance, if the integer part of the real palindrome is 123 then the palindrome **must be** 123.321.

These observations should be a solid starting place for you to approach the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

For a brute-force approach, just keep adding the smallest decimal until the number is a palindrone.

Comment: Define "smallest decimal".

Comment: I mean the smallest mulitple of 1/10 that the number contains.  EG: 112.24 would be 0.01

Comment: Since the decimal is relevant I do not think this necessarily works. For instance if the number is 100.1 then you will never actually reach a palindrome.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.  In that case it would need to start with the inverse of the largest power of ten.  eg: 112.24 would be 0.001.  If the highest number carries over, it would need to restart the scan.  Though I'm sure there's a better (more mathy) way to find it :-)

Comment: @KevinSeifert I think you would have to take the minimum of the two approaches. 112.2401 is a counter example to your most recent suggestion ;) Though I suppose at that point you could just round to the correct precision and include the difference in your final answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no **lower** to that problem.

Proof: (Suppose numbers are members of a list)

Numbers = [a, b, c, d] (decimal is ignored right?)

Then you can append the reverse of the list and you'll have a pallindrome.

Palindrome = [a, b, c, d, d, c, b, a]

But note that we add a `0` between `d`s and it stays a palindrome.

We can add infinitely many `0`s and the number we get (..00..00000dcba) is always smaller, so there exists no smaller, real number making a number a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a hint, I can recommend examining the digits from left to right first. For example, if you have the number 12, then you would just add the first digit to obtain 121 which is a palindrome.

If you have 983, then look at the 9. Adding 9 will not make it a palindrome, so look at the 8. Add 89 and you will have a palindrome 98389.

@pankgeorg From the OP, I believe adding 000001 is effectively just adding 1. Therefore you cannot keep appending infinitely many 0's to the solution to make it smaller (000001 = 1).

Comment: Though ... he doesn't need to concatenate the number strings ("1" + "1" = "11") .. he need to find what number to add (983+x= symmetrical)

Comment: Yep. But the problem asks not only for a number that added to the given number makes a palindrome. It needs to be the smaller one... In you case, adding 0.21 ... we have the palindrome 12.21

Comment: Well, given that information, if the number is not a decimal then you should always be able to deduce that the answer will be a value between 0 and 1. Because any number could be made a palindrome by adding the reverse of itself as a decimal. (10243 -> 10243.34201, for example).